# How can I know a particular SQL query is executed successfully in MySQL without looking at my database?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to execute a SQL query in Mysql. how can I know a particular SQL query is executed successfully in MySQL without looking at my database?
Here is my code:

```
     if(cur.execute("update student set Date =current_date() where 
        Serial_number=1")):

                print("[+] QR Code detected, data:", data)
                messagebox.showinfo('message','your recorded in time is 
                                                               '+addout_time)
```

When I am looking at my database my query has been executed successfully but the code under if block is not executed. I want to know why the code under if block is not executed.

Comment: you can check affected rows.

Comment: @Devsi Odedra thanks for your response but I want to ask how can I check without looking at my databse.

Comment: Reverse your logic and check for failure